# Cycles - Bake - Black patches

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I have been trying to figure out why my object is rendering so dark. I have been messing with diffuse and other settings through reading other help forumns. I still can't figure out what the issue is and now I am getting a big black box in my painting. Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

The blender file is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q6TLXFYbRHifzNpNDP_BfoBC_qcXwLb9

[image]

Comment: The .blend that you gave us doesn't produce the same result as your images, so please edit your question to match versions. For the black box (white for us) in the center though: There is an object in front of your coloured image: https://imgur.com/a/dp5rYr1

Comment: @WhatAMesh that is the blend file I used to create the images I gave you - I just double checked. Does that mean something in my settings is off?

Comment: Nevermind, my bad, I thought you show us render output, but this is the bake output.

Comment: @WhatAMesh I figured out the black box, another object was blocking it - thanks for that tip! But it is still baking much darker than what it looks like rendered.

Comment: What do you mean by dark render output? It renders like this for me https://imgur.com/a/PXaPJBQ (I hope it is okay to upload the render, otherwise let me know)

Comment: Well if you look at the material for the photo, the photo is actually much brighter in the image than what it renders. Also, the front of the frame (bottom left of the bake) doesn't have any of the graininess that the top/sides do. Is this a lighting issue? I tried playing with global illumination etc and get get the front to be bright like the top of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

The object (s4studio_1) in front of your "photography" generates black "patch", it causes graininess (noise) as well.

The object is disabled from Global Viewport, but not from Rendering (Bake).
Disabling the object from Render solves the issue.

[image]

[image]

The darker appearance of photography can be solved by changing value of Mix Shader from 0.7 to 0.5, but for more info of mixing Diffuse/Glosy try this
[Confusing problem when I'm trying to mix Diffuse with Glossy shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67058/confusing-problem-when-im-trying-to-mix-diffuse-with-glossy-shader)

[image]

BTW: Lightning your scene by strong "Ambient Oclusion" (1.75) doesn't seem to be a good way for some natural result. Your four lamps are not (visibly) lightning the scene anymore. Deleting them you can see any difference. In this screen only World color (HSV 0/0/0.8) and Sun strenght 3 does the job.